# converting string map to json using jsoncpp

Tags: c++, json, jsoncpp

I am using jsoncpp, is there a way to put a map in Json::Value ?

I understand I can extract keys one by one and put them in the Json::Value. but is there a more graceful way  ? for example in the C# counter part NewtonSoft json api

I would do

```
      String json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cmdDict);
```

Comment: [ThorsSerializer](https://github.com/Loki-Astari/ThorsSerializer) supports converting standard C++ types to/from JSON automatically. Any user defined types can also be streamed simply by adding a single declaration for that type.

Answer (score 0):

jsoncpp doesn't support that.

Two C++ libraries that do support conversion between JSON and C++ types are [nlohmann](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) and [jsoncons](https://github.com/danielaparker/jsoncons) (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54318130/cpp-json-parser-in-cpp-that-provide-support-serialize-deserialize-feature-conv/55187898#55187898)). Note that C++ does not have introspection, so the mappings between your custom C++ types and JSON need to be set up explicitly, according to the specifications of the library.